# What would be the advantages/disadvantages of prefixing column names with the item name?

Tags: database-design

I am working on a blog module to use in my future project.

I decided to prefix all the table names with `blog_` since it's a module and different modules can have some tables with the same name.

Yesterday I was looking the source code of IPS Boards and saw something like this. The point interested me was that they used prefixes for their column names too.

As an example:

```
blog_categories
    category_id
    category_name
    category_slug
```

or

```
blog_categories
    id
    name
    slug
```

Which one do you think it would be better if I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To some extent this is flamewar territory, so this post will discuss why I think people choose one or the other.  Personally I am in the latter category.  Note some pros and cons depend on your database system.

**Reasons to add prefixes**

With prefixes, your column names are largely semantically unique.  category_id always refers to the id of the category table.  Some people think this is easier to read.  Others point out that this allows joins to use `USING ()` since that means the join columns always have the same name.

Unfortunately the latter case is not perfect.  `USING ()` limits what the planner can do with a join since re-ordering joins can change the join criteria.  Good planners might be able to get around this however.  Check your database documentation for details.

**Reasons not to add prefixes**

I prefer however not to add prefixes.  In this model, the columns are all logically bound to the primary key of the table, so using the table as a namespace works well  This also allows simpler, more consistent naming regarding significance within a table.  A numeric surrogate key for example might always be called `id` while other columns may have other names.

Part of my preference however may be related to my choice of database. PostgreSQL doesn't make a really hard distinction (the way InnoDB does) regarding primary key vs not null unique constraints.  Therefore I find that naming surrogate keys consistently is nice, particularly when I try to always designate natural primary keys.  This approach however does not work so well on all database systems.

Comment: Thanks for great answer, according to your research and the way I code, O will stick with the second option. I am using Eloquent as a database helper so I don't really mess with SQL queries. I also think it's more readable that way.